# How to prevent Firefox DevTools from showing "Source Map not found" errors?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am using a couple of 3rd party minified Javascript files that have no .map file.  When I am debugging in Firefox DevTools, it consistently shows these errors:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://foo.domain.com/widgets/widgets.min.js
Source Map URL: widgets.min.js.map
```

This is really distracting since there are a number of these files and they really pollute the console.

Is there anyway to turn these warnings off?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable source maps globally by going into the `Toolbox Options` of the Developper Tools and unchecking `Enable Source Maps`.

You can also provide an empty source map for some specific JavaScript files. Use a local copy of the files (at least during development) and modify the source maps directive:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=http://example.com/path/to/your/sourcemap.map
```

by pointing to an empty source map file. You can also just remove the source map directive from the file.

Comment: The problem is that .map file is missing from a domain I don't control.  And I'd rather not turn off the functionality entirely because I rely on it.

Comment: Can you use a local copy of the library and modify the source map directive, or juste remove it?

Comment: I had to close and re-open Dev Tools before that setting took effect.

Comment: Thank you! I'm hosting a downloaded JS file without source maps, removing the source map directive totally helped.